# Error whilst moving file to a folder in Swift

Tags: swift

Ok, gotta be honest, I am kind of a noob at Swift.

Anyways, I tried using `FileManager.default.moveItem` for a project of mine but it always results in errors.

Any fixes/problems that I may have done?

Command I used:

```
$ ./movefile file.sh folder/
```

Code:

```swift
import Foundation

var filemgr = FileManager.default

var fp1 = CommandLine.arguments[1]
var fp2 = CommandLine.arguments[2]

do {
    try filemgr.moveItem(atPath: fp1, toPath: fp2)
} catch {
    print("Error.")
}
```

Comment: Start by printing the actual error: `print(error)`.

Comment: Also please read the documentation. You will note that `toPath` must include the name of the file at its new target. I would also guess that the path will have to be absolute.